# I am Trying to Save Multiple Dictionaries to a List at a Time Whilst Keeping Their Values, But It Isn't Working

Tags: python, dictionary, save

```
itemsInExistence = [{'name': 'Tester', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 1, 'amount': 1}, {'name': 'Mk II Death', 'stats': 10, 'rank': 5, 'amount': 3}]
def save_list2():
  f = open('all_items.txt', 'w')
  ii = 0
  for item in itemsInExistence:
    print(f.write(itemsInExistence[ii][0], ''))
    f.write(itemsInExistence[ii][1] + ' ')
    f.write(itemsInExistence[ii][2] + ' ') 
    f.write(itemsInExistence[ii][3] + '\n')
    ii += 1
```

Where it says f.write(itemsInExistence[ii][0], '') it is giving me the error

KeyError: 0

Why is this and what does it mean? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use `item["name"]`, `item["stats"]` etc. There are no keys in your dict for 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: In the code the first line would already produce a syntax error. Better copy & paste your code into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ggorlen said, use names as keys.

```py
itemsInExistence = [{'name': 'Tester', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 1, 'amount': 1},
                    {'name': 'Mk II Death', 'stats': 10, 'rank': 5, 'amount': 3}]

def save_list2():
    with open('all_items.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in itemsInExistence:
            f.write('{name} {stats} {rank} {amount}\n'.format(**item))
```

<del>You need Python 3 for this example.</del>

EDIT: I've changed `print(..., file=f)` to `f.write(...)`, now it works in py2 and py3.

EDIT2: Some explanation.

`with` statement close file [automatically](https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Lists `list` or `[]` use positive integer indexes (`0`, `1` etc.)
Dictionaries `dict` or `{}` use keys (in your examples `'name'`, `'stats'` etc.). See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html).

`for` statement iterates by list items or by dict keys. You don't need `ii`, `item` is content of list item, which is dict.

```py
for item in [1, 4, 'ala']:
   print(item)
# prints:
# 1
# 4
# 'ala'

for key in {'anwer': 42, 'sto': 100, 1: 'first'}:
    print(key)
# prints:
# 'answer'
# 'sto'
# 1
```

You can access dict values by `my_dict[key]` or iterate by values `for value in my_dict.values` or by keys and values: `for key, value in my_dict.items()`.

I've used keyword arguments `**item`. In function call `func(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})` means `func(a=1, b=2)`.

String format `''.format()` (or format-string `f''` since Python 3.6) allows put data directly to string with [advanced syntax](https://pyformat.info).